# How can I set a timer for different game modes?

Tags: ios, timer, xcode6

I am developing a game for class where a timer is ran when a button is pressed.

```
-(void)setTimer{

self->mTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(buttonNotPushed) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
}


-(void)resetTimer{
[self->mTimer invalidate];
self->mTimer = nil;
```

Here is a snippet of how the timer code is used.

```
- (IBAction)yellowDot1:(id)sender {
if ([_labelColor.text isEqualToString:@"Yellow"]) {

    [ self Scoring];
    [self label];
    [self resetTimer];
    [self setTimer];
}
    else ([self GameOver]);
}


- (IBAction)redDot1:(id)sender {


if ([_labelColor.text isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {

    [ self Scoring];
    [self label];
    [self resetTimer];
    [self setTimer];
}
    else ([self GameOver]);
}
```

The game presents with a Play button which modals over to the next screen. Currently at 5 seconds, I would like to create a "difficult" mode where at the home screen, the user clicks on a "difficult" button and the timer for the game runs at 2 seconds instead. Right now, I am contemplating duplicating my storyboard and view controllers and going that way where I just make the timer a different interval. Is a shorter way possible through code for a difficult mode?

Comment: `else ([self GameOver]);` is pretty weird styling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply declare a global a variable for this. Use a class (maybe a singleton) that holds the mode and use a `-(float) getGameDuration;` method

lets say...

```
// GameHandler.h
static GameHandler *sharedInstance = nil;

@interface GameHandler : NSObject 
{
    GameMode *mode;
}

typedef enum{
    GAMEMODE_EASY = 0,
    GAMEMODE_NORMAL,
    GAMEMODE_HARD
} GameMode;



-(float) getGameDuration;
```

implementation

```
// GameHandler.m

+ (GameHandler *)sharedInstance // implement singleton
{};

-(float) getGameDuration
{
    switch(mode)
    {
        case GAMEMODE_EASY:
            return 10.f;
        case GAMEMODE_NORMAL:
            return 5.f;
        case GAMEMODE_HARD:
            return 2.f;
    }
    return 5.f;
}

// your other classes

float gameDurration = [[GameHandler sharedInstance] getGameDuration];
self->mTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:gameDurration
                                                target:self 
                                              selector:@selector(buttonNotPushed) 
                                              userInfo:nil 
                                               repeats:NO];
```

Comment: @StephenRao any comment? could it help you, bad solution, any other problems?